# I want to update the data in table 1 from table 2 matching the first name and last name from both tables

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I want to update the data of the columns `ew.DLR_CDE` and `ew.JOB_CDE`  in table 1 (`EW_PEREGRN.DCI_DLR_CRSE_INFO`) from table 2 (`MOREKIR.DCI_DLR_CRSE_INFO_STG`) matching on the first name and last name tables 1. Also the table 2 does not have any unique field. Kindly help me with the SQL query

I was trying the query shown below, but I get an error:

> [Error] Execution (15: 1): ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

```
MERGE INTO EW_PEREGRN.DCI_DLR_CRSE_INFO ew
USING (SELECT *
       FROM MOREKIR.DCI_DLR_CRSE_INFO_STG) mk ON (ew.FRST_NME = mk.FRST_NME 
                                              AND ew.LAST_NME = mk.LAST_NME)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET ew.DLR_CDE = mk.DLR_CDE, 
            ew.JOB_CDE = mk.JOB_CDE
```

Comment: That usually means you have duplicates in the staging table, so for a given first/last name it doesn't know which values to use in the update. If the duplicate first/last names always have the same dlr/job code pair - and its other column value that differ - then you can work around that in the merge. Otherwise you need to decide what you want to happen in that scenario - how would you decide which values to use? Including sample data that causes the error might be helpful.

Comment: The staging tables does not have the duplicate first names and last names. The main table has to match the first name and last name from staging tables and update the remaining columns data from staging table into the main table

Comment: Are you sure? [That's what the error is saying](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e3753afc4744f3f06b9a243da0e2dce). (That db<>fiddle includes a query to identify duplicates, which I think will show something when run against your real data too.)

Comment: The main table has duplicates and i want to update all the data in the main table matching the unique first name and last name in the staging table

Comment: Duplicates in the main table [wouldn't cause that error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a32b63027c693d13e77ad6101b9d627c) though.

Comment: What does running the following query give you? `SELECT first_nme, last_nme, COUNT(*) FROM MOREKIR.DCI_DLR_CRSE_INFO_STG GROUP BY first_nme, last_nme HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;` If there are results, you have rows in your staging table that contain duplicates of your supposedly unique first and last name columns.